# Put image aligned left on a fixed navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a transparent navigation bar that is fixed, and i am trying to get an image, or even just text aligned to the left. The following is the html code and css code I am using:

-------------------------------------------html code------------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <b>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Our Apps</a>
            <a href="#">Support</a>
            <a href="#">Press</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </b>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        Content Here!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

-------------------------------------------------CSS Code------------------------------------------

```
body {
    padding: 0; /* Gets rid of the automatic padding */
    margin: 0;  /*  on HTML documents */
    font-family: Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}

#navigation a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

#navigation a:visited {
    color: white;
}
#content {
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thanks for any help!
-Aaron

Comment: Not able to understand your requirements clearly. Do you want to align any element or set an image?
It will be helpful for us if you create jsfiddle for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css floats.

CSS

```
#navigation div.block-left {
   float: left;
}

#navigation div.block-right {
   float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
   <div id="navigation">
   <div class="block-left">
     Put stuff here!
   </div>
    <div class="block-left">
      <b>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">Our Apps</a>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
        <a href="#">Press</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </b>
    </div>
```

Because both blocks are floating left they will stack in order from left to right.

Also, you shouldn't be using  anymore as afaik its deprecated.  Better options would be  or

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to explain further, but if I correctly understood what you want, you might try this:

```
#navigation {
    background-image: url('path/to/img.gif');
}
```

Comment: That will not work, I already have a navigation bar with a background but everything is centered so i am looking to escape that and align an image on the left hand side of the navigation bar. If you would like to see go to http://aaronvigal.com/hey/index.html